# D3 Targeting/Control Over Specific Arcs

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I am trying to target individual arcs in the inner donut. I want to be able to have control over each arc(14 of them) and change their colors accordingly. Currently I want to have 2 colors, either gray or the lime green. Essentially this is a 2-week progress checker. If a user participates 7 of the 14 days I want it to show 7 green 7 grey, etc.

Here is my codepen for it. Thank you in advance.

```
    $(function(){
    var tooltip = d3.select(".tooltip");
    var $container = $('.chart-container'),
        τ = 2 * Math.PI,
        width = $container.width(),
        height = $container.height(),
        innerRadius = Math.min(width,height)/4,
        //innerRadius = (outerRadius/4)*3,
        fontSize = (Math.min(width,height)/4);

var dataset = {
  days: [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    progress: [1]

};

var participation = 100;    

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#7EBA4A"]);



// Create the donut pie chart layout
  var pie = d3.layout.pie()
  .sort(null);

// Determine size of arcs
var arc = d3.svg.arc();

// Append SVG attributes and append g to the SVG
var svg = d3.select('.chart-container').append("svg")
  .attr("width", '100%')
  .attr("height", '100%')
  .attr('viewBox','0 0 '+Math.min(width,height) +' '+Math.min(width,height) )
  .attr('preserveAspectRatio','xMinYMin')
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" +  width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");


var gs = svg.selectAll("g").data(d3.values(dataset)).enter().append("g").attr("class", "arc");

var path = gs.selectAll("path")
  .data(function(d) { return pie(d); })
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
  .attr("d", function(d, i, j) { return arc.innerRadius(innerRadius+(20*j)).outerRadius(innerRadius+20+(20*j))(d); })
  .attr("class", function(d, i, j) { if (i>=participation && j<1) return "passed" ; })

// Append text to the inner circle
svg.append("text")
  .attr("dy", "0.5em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("class", "inner-circle")
  .attr("fill", "#36454f")
  .text(function(d) { return "100%"; });
});
```

http://codepen.io/pen/MwdPpx?editors=011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed your data format a little bit to simplify :

```
var daysProgress = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
```

1 represents a day participated and 0 not participated.

Here your modified codepen (displays green if day partcipated, grey if not, with total percentage in the center):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqZPPx

Comment: That is very close to what i want it to do! Thank you so much :D

Comment: Do you know if theres anyway to maintain the outside circle "participation" as well?

Comment: Yes it should be possible, but I don't understand what should appear on this outside circle ? Could you explain to me please ?

Comment: Sorry my internet crapped out and never submitted the rest of the comment. 

So, im trying to get the inside of the donut to have a fill. This donut is representing participation progress. 

Green = Responded Yes
Grey = Responded No
Black = No response

So essentially, it would start at 100% and on days where a user forgets to participate, the arc-color is "black". Whenever there are days where it is black, I would like to have the inside fill color drop accordingly to the correct percentage.

Comment: I would like for it to look something like this but in percent

https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/447132980255809536/rBfwYfkY_400x400.png

http://feic31.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Level-Money.jpg

Comment: You could try to integrate this example : 
http://bl.ocks.org/brattonc/5e5ce9beee483220e2f6

Comment: Codename44 thank you for being so helpful!!!

Mind if i ask you for one more suggestion/help?

Another approach i would like to take is to have another donut sit outside of the "arc" donut but is still dependent on the data of the inner donut. So that it looks something like this http://codepen.io/iamsok/pen/bdyxWB.

The outside donut would take into account only the "black" arc and according to that percentage feed back the amount to be shaded in. For example, if there are 7 of the 14 arcs black, then it would shade in 50% of the outside donut

Comment: You're welcome! Could you accept answer if topic is closed ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that